# How to setup session based database connections with Sinatra, Sequel and Rack

Tags: ruby, rack, sequel, puma

I am using Sequel with Sinatra in a Puma / Rack server.

I wish to store my Sequel DB connection object with the session - not globally - so that I can have a separate pool of DB connections for each logged on user.   The intent is to have one database server logon for each web server logon.

I cannot work out how to do this since the Sequel database object appears to be  global singleton.   If for example I attempt to serialize the database object and store in the session I will get an error message: `TypeError - can't dump anonymous class:`   I don't want to have to connect to the database on every route request.

How can I do this?   Here is some sample code that hopefully indicates what I am trying to achieve:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'pp'
require 'sequel'
require 'json'
require 'java'            
require 'sqljdbc4.jar'
require 'yaml'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  set :sessions, true

  use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
      :expire_after => 2592000,
      :secret => 'sydasx'

  get '/' do
    db = session[:db]
    DB = YAML::Load(db)

    response = ''
    DB['select * from SEC_USER'].each do |row|
      response += row.to_s
    end

    response.to_json
  end

  get '/login/:username' do

    username = params['username']

    puts "username: #{username}"

    conn_str = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databaseName=#{username};integratedSecurity=true;"    
    DB = Sequel.connect(conn_str)
    puts "DB: #{DB.pretty_inspect}"
    db = YAML::dump(DB)
    puts "db: #{db}"

    session[:db] = db

    "logged in"
  end

end
```

Comment: Hmm - just wondering - is another way of asking this - does Rack allow session state to be stored in memory - or does state for session always need to be serialized?

Comment: Oh - just adding the DB objects to a global hash seems to do it.  I guess that is going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't serialize the Sequel::Database object.  You have a few decent options:

1. Use a rack middleware that creates a Sequel::Database object per request, using the object only for the request.  In this case you wouldn't assign the result of Sequel.connect to a constant, you would pass a block and call the next variable inside that block.
2. Create a single Sequel::Database object at top level and store it in the DB constant.  The the arbitrary_servers and server_block extensions into the Sequel::Database object. Then use a rack middleware that checks out a connection to the appropriate server for the duration of the block.
3. If you have few customers, it's possible to just use Sequel's sharding support and use just the server_block extension without arbitrary_servers.  One advantage of doing that is that connections can be cached so you aren't making a separate database connection per request (which would be the case for both 1. and 2.).
4. Use a global hash as you mentioned, with keys being user names and values being Sequel::Database objects.  You need to make sure you have enough memory to store all the objects you want to track if you do this.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.   Option 2 sounds interesting.   We realized that we have a similar problem with model classes that inherit from `Sequel::Model` which are global singletons that include a database connection.   Option 2 might solve that problem as well.